# Firestore chat private and group

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have this chat structure for groups and private in real time, is there any way to structure to get the images and names of the people who chat? currently using UserIds I do a separate query to get it, but if someone changes their name or image it won't update.
[image]

Comment: Code please. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: what? I do not understand

Comment: Your code and what is platfrom (e.g Flutter, Javascript....)

Answer (score 0):

You typically would start a RTDB listener for the nodes of the RTDB that contain the information for each of the users.  Alternatively, you could copy all of the relevant user information into "current chats" and if a user changes their profile information you could also copy that new information into any "current chat" sessions.

In my app, I maintain user profile information in a `profile` collection in Firestore, and maintain the chat details in RTDB.  So I have a realtime listener for the chat (RTDB) and a realtime listener for `firestore.collection('profile').where('uid', 'in', arrayOfUserIDsInChat)`.

(Currently the way I have things, I am limited to the number of user profiles I can listen to ... `in` is limited to 10 ... but that is sufficient for my current requirements)

Comment: This is how I have it, for each ID of my array, I add a realtime listener, it does not seem "efficient" to me since my chat list would be updated from several places and it would create problems in the threads of my application.